# How to plot this graph in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have CSV with the following data

[image]

There are 500 rows of this series. However, I need to plot whatever on A column as horizontal axis and B column [0..499] as vertical. If possible I would like to label horizontal axis values on each 10.000. This is what I want to achieve

[image: test]
<sub>(source: [bucknell.edu](https://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/elessonsHTML/Sensors/SensorTvsR.gif))</sub>

[Sample data from [200...499]](http://pastebin.com/fxUQ2S4J)

Comment: What version of excel are you using?  I know for sure this can be acheived in Excel 2010..

Comment: 2010 it is! My hair goes white...

Comment: I've also updated my post with sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Complete rewrite.

Select the two columns of data, with the first column being the X axis.  Then insert a scatter chart.

[image: Scatter Chart]

(And here I thought the line graph was the easy one.)

If you want to display the numbers as kilo-ohms, I suggest you divide the numbers in the column by 1000 and use the custom number format: `0" kΩ"`

Even better, don't divide the original data. use a custom number format of `0," kΩ"` where the comma after the zero removes three zeros to show thousands. In the same way `0,," MΩ"` has two commas, so three sets of three zeros are removed, showing millions.

Comment: Sorry, but that's what I've tried already. It doesn't give me `A` column as horizontal axis! When I try to specify column `B` in horizontal axis, I get whole chart screwed...

Comment: If you are sure about solution, could you plz post a screenshot which looks similar to the graph above? To me it doesn't look like I can achieve it in Excel, just because my A column data, which should rest on horizontal axis, doesn't have exact same "ticks" as it should have. So somehow Excel should take all data and approximate for 10000, 20000, ... 50000. Moreover, it should somehow limit horizontal axis up to 50000. In the A column there is even value with 2000000, which should be dropped out. Do you still think Excel can make it?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused as to which way around you wanted it.  I've rewritten my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Select Column B, go to Insert tab, click on the line graph.

When the graph is in, right-click on it, click 'select data', click on 'edit' on the right (below horizontal category axis label), select column A, click OK.

Comment: The line chart is what the OP got, where categories were shows by counting numbers 1, 2, 3, etc. Only an XY Scatter chart will use numerical values from the data as X values.